# Loading dummy crystal report to load the .dll's into memory

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

Since Crystal report takes a long time to load on the first run, I found a solution on the internet suggesting to load a dummy report, so that the dll's will be loaded into the memory before hand.

For this purpose I used another thread & this is being executed in the application startup event. Here is the related code

```
Dim dummyRPTThread As New Thread(AddressOf loadDummyReport)
dummyRPTThread.IsBackground = True
dummyRPTThread.Start()
```

This seems to solve the excessive load time issue but on the odd occasion the following error pops up.

*The program can't start because cxlibw-5-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.*

After I click OK on the error dialog the application starts up normally & reports also work. How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: I suppose you've seen this? Others have had success: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3203841

Comment: hmm. I did not see that thread, thanks.. I will test the solution suggested there.

Comment: In this page you have the solution: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1426543-program-cant-start-because-cxlibw-5-0-dll-is-missing-error-in-dynamics I had same problem and it worked for me